# How to check whether inputs are of same type and size in R?

Tags: r

I want to write a function that accepts only vectors of same size, and only matrices of same size, how can I achieve this?

I have a function like shown below, but it clearly won't work like that, because if I have valid vectors, I will get an error that they are not valid matrices, and if they are valid matrices vice versa. But, as I said I only want to check whether they are vector or matrix, and whether they are of same size, only if they are of same type and size I want to continue with the function.

```
testFunc <- function(x, y)
{
  if (!(is.vector(x) && is.vector(y) && is.numeric(x) && is.numeric(y) && length(x) == length(y)))
    stop("Invalid input.")
  if (!(is.matrix(x) && is.matrix(y) && is.numeric(x) && is.numeric(y) && dim(x) == dim(y)))
    stop("Invalid input.")

   # Rest of the function
}
```

How can I make these checks, and in most concise way?

Comment: Depending on what exactly you want to be the same, you may be able to shorten some of the suggestions below by using `is.vector(x, "numeric")` and skipping `is.numeric`, being careful to note that any attributes other than names will cause it to return `FALSE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is pretty good. You can do a little more concise like this:

```
if (!(is.numeric(x) && is.numeric(y) && 
      ((is.vector(x) && is.vector(y) && length(x) == length(y))||
       (is.matrix(x) && is.matrix(y) && dim(x) == dim(y)))))
stop("Invalid input.")
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I was missing. Thanks.